# What is the best way to keep two bzr repositories in sync?

Tags: sync, bazaar

I would like to keep a bzr repository in sync between my laptop and desktop. Is there any special tool to accomplish this, or should I just use rsync? I would absolutely love it if I could get one that would automatically synchronize and let the newer version win.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to make the the repository in one location "bound" to the other. With this option, bzr acts more like a tradition vcs than a dvcs. Each commit in the "bound" branch is automatically pushed to its parent. Though this is generally designed with the idea that the parent will not have working trees. As I imagine you want to hack on both your laptop and desktop, that's not the case. You'll have to run `bzr update` for the working tree to be updated.

There is an automirror plugin that I haven't used. It hasn't been active for awhile, but it might just be feature complete.

See:

http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrUsingBoundBranches

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630846/598929

http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/automirror-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

That is kind of the whole point of a DVCS.  Just use bzr to push/pull between the two repositories.